# AWS Lambda: Can I return context and have a task still running?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Right now I have a lambda function in production that processes log strings and then return them to the client, so:

```
1) string received by lambda
2) lambda transforms string
3) lambda returns via context.succeed the transformed string
```

Now I am adding an additional step that will save the string in a dynamodb table, so the workflow will be:

```
1) string received by lambda
2) lambda transforms string
3) lambda saves string to dynamo 
4) lambda returns via context.succeed the transformed string
```

Right now the bit the saves the function is something like:

```
function _saveItem (item) {
    dynamo.putItem(item, function (err, data) {
        //error handling here
        context.succeed(JSON.stringify(item));
    })
}
```

I'd like to know if it's somehow possible to fire the `putItem` function and, without waiting for it to end, return the item via `context.succeed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a "RequestResponse" style invoke. Is that true?

If you want your value returned right away you can always invoke another Lambda function (using an "Event" invoke), and have that function write to DDB, and then return the value.

The "event" invoke will run asynchronously in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the short answer is that the asynchronous call will not complete once context.succeed is called.  However, you can really learn more about Lambda and this use case more in detail through [this blog post.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/)